# How to label all rows between two particular character values in a column in r?

Tags: r

## Problem Description

The `start` and `end` in the `frame_type` column (below) refer to the start and end of a lane change by a car. For each `id` of a driver, I want to label all the rows from start to end as "LC" in a new column.

## Data

```
foo <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 10)),
                  frame_type = rep(c(".", ".", ".", 
                                     "start", ".", "lcf", ".",
                                     ".", "end", "."), 3))
> foo
   id frame_type
1   1          .
2   1          .
3   1          .
4   1      start
5   1          .
6   1        lcf
7   1          .
8   1          .
9   1        end
10  1          .
11  1          .
12  1          .
13  1          .
14  1      start
15  1          .
16  1        lcf
17  1          .
18  1          .
19  1        end
20  1          .
21  2          .
22  2          .
23  2          .
24  2      start
25  2          .
26  2        lcf
27  2          .
28  2          .
29  2        end
30  2          .
```

## Desired Output:

```
> foo
   id frame_type  LC
1   1          .   .
2   1          .   .
3   1          .   .
4   1      start LC1
5   1          . LC1
6   1        lcf LC1
7   1          . LC1
8   1          . LC1
9   1        end LC1
10  1          .   .
11  1          .   .
12  1          .   .
13  1          .   .
14  1      start LC2
15  1          . LC2
16  1        lcf LC2
17  1          . LC2
18  1          . LC2
19  1        end LC2
20  1          .   .
21  2          .   .
22  2          .   .
23  2          .   .
24  2      start LC1
25  2          . LC1
26  2        lcf LC1
27  2          . LC1
28  2          . LC1
29  2        end LC1
30  2          .   .
```

I have searched a lot but couldn't get any ideas to solve this problem. The closest thing I know is `tidyr::fill()`, but that doesn't work in this case. I want to use `dplyr::group_by()` because there are several `id`s. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(foo, foo$id), function(a){
    temp = inverse.rle(with(rle(cumsum(a$frame_type == "start") -
                                    cumsum(head(c(FALSE, a$frame_type == "end"), -1))),
                            list(lengths = lengths,
                                 values = replace(values, values == 1,
                                                  seq_along(values[values == 1])))))
    a$LC = replace(paste0("LC", temp), temp == 0, ".")
    a
}))
#     id frame_type  LC
#1.1   1          .   .
#1.2   1          .   .
#1.3   1          .   .
#1.4   1      start LC1
#1.5   1          . LC1
#1.6   1        lcf LC1
#1.7   1          . LC1
#1.8   1          . LC1
#1.9   1        end LC1
#1.10  1          .   .
#1.11  1          .   .
#1.12  1          .   .
#1.13  1          .   .
#1.14  1      start LC2
#1.15  1          . LC2
#1.16  1        lcf LC2
#1.17  1          . LC2
#1.18  1          . LC2
#1.19  1        end LC2
#1.20  1          .   .
#2.21  2          .   .
#2.22  2          .   .
#2.23  2          .   .
#2.24  2      start LC1
#2.25  2          . LC1
#2.26  2        lcf LC1
#2.27  2          . LC1
#2.28  2          . LC1
#2.29  2        end LC1
#2.30  2          .   .
```

Comment: Thank you! `rle()` is really useful.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(foo)`), grouped by the cumulative sum of logical vector (`frame_type == "start"`), `if` `any` 'frame_type' have the 'start' string, then get the row index (`.I`) of the sequence of position from 'start' to 'end', extract that column (`$V1`), use that as `i` to create a new column 'LC' by `paste`ing the string `"LC"` with the cumulative sum of logical index grouped by 'id'.  If needed, the `NA` values can be changed to `.` (not recommended)

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(foo)[ , if(any(frame_type == "start")) .I[which(frame_type == 
       "start"):which(frame_type == "end")], cumsum(frame_type == "start")]$V1
foo[i1, LC := paste0("LC", cumsum(frame_type == "start")),  id
   ][is.na(LC), LC := "."][]
#    id frame_type  LC
# 1:  1          .   .
# 2:  1          .   .
# 3:  1          .   .
# 4:  1      start LC1
# 5:  1          . LC1
# 6:  1        lcf LC1
# 7:  1          . LC1
# 8:  1          . LC1
# 9:  1        end LC1
#10:  1          .   .
#11:  1          .   .
#12:  1          .   .
#13:  1          .   .
#14:  1      start LC2
#15:  1          . LC2
#16:  1        lcf LC2
#17:  1          . LC2
#18:  1          . LC2
#19:  1        end LC2
#20:  1          .   .
#21:  2          .   .
#22:  2          .   .
#23:  2          .   .
#24:  2      start LC1
#25:  2          . LC1
#26:  2        lcf LC1
#27:  2          . LC1
#28:  2          . LC1
#29:  2        end LC1
#30:  2          .   .
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for these sample data, but for my original data it throws `Error in which(frame_type == "start"):which(frame_type == "end") : 
  argument of length 0` for some reason.

Comment: @umairdurrani  I have taken care of cases where there are no 'start' for the grouping variable with `cumsum`.  Do you also have cases where there are only 'end'